# Describing an algorithm at most O(nm log n) run time

Tags: algorithm

If I had to give an algorithm in O|V|3| that takes as input a directed graph with positive edge lengths and returns the length of the shortest cycle in the graph (if the graph is acyclic, it should say so). I know that it will be:
Let G be a graph, define a matrix Dij which stores the shortest path from vertex i to j for any pair of vertices u,v. There can be two shortest paths between u and v. The length of the cycle is Duv+ Dvu. This then is enough to compote the minimum of the Duv+Dvu for any given pair of vertices u and v.

Could I write this in a way to make it at most O(nm log n) (where n is the number of vertices and m is the number of edges) instead of O|V|3|?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.   First, research algorithms for solving the problem; this is well-traveled ground.  Second, post your attempted solution algorithm with analysis, preferably in clear steps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact this problem can be solved in O(*nm*) according to a conference paper by Orlin and Sedeño-Noda (2017), titled [An O(*nm*) time algorithm for finding the min length directed cycle in a graph](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3039808):

> In this paper, we introduce an O(*nm*) time algorithm to determine the minimum length directed cycle (also called the "minimum weight directed cycle") in a directed network with *n* nodes and *m* arcs and with no negative length directed cycles.